# Solve does not seem to work for this equation

Tags: equation-solving

I need to solve the following equation, for which I am using Solve as below

```
λ = 20;
μ =  3.1623;

Solve[
      Integrate[Exp[-λ π km r^2 ArcTan[r Sqrt[μ]]] 2 Gamma[λ π + 1] / Gamma[λ π]
                r (1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ π), {r, 0, Infinity}] == 0.5,
      km]
```

But Mathematica does not output anything. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Solve` and `Integrate` try to solve for the exact value, which takes a lot of time or, in some cases, is impossible. You may want to use `NSolve` and `NIntegrate`.

```
λ = 20;
μ = 3.1623;
f[km_Real] := NIntegrate[Exp[-λ*π*km*r^2*ArcTan[r*Sqrt[μ]]]
 *2*Gamma[λ*π + 1]/Gamma[λ*π]*r*(1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ*π), {r, 0, Infinity}];
NSolve[f[km]==.5, km]
(* {{km -> 5.25146}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me! However, if I want to find the expression for $km$, it is possible?

Comment: It seems impossible. Mathematica is unable to calculate the integral `Integrate[Exp[-λ*π*km*r^2*ArcTan[r*Sqrt[μ]]]*2*Gamma[λ*π + 1]/Gamma[λ*π]*r*(1 - r^2)^(-1 + λ*π), {r, 
   0, Infinity}]`. Inputting it outputs the integral itself, not a simplified equation. That is, Mathematica cannot create an inverse function and give the exact expression for `km`.